Man is a demi-god but can't remember it
In the movie I saw, It was a handsome guy in his 30's I swear it was (Paul Walker but maybe not) The guy ended up being a sort of high rank demi-god.  His wife seems to know this and keeps it from him.  He created the Earth, people and reality he's living in, but apparently, he's been doing it for so long that he's forgotten everything about the heavenly realm he came from.  There's a man and a woman that pursue him.  He remains very confused through the movie as he's contacted.  They've been trying to intervene in his reality because he's been missing for so long.  His wife tries to protect him from this truth. It was a clever movie and I'd love to be able to identify it.  Thank you so much for the help.

Why not just go back through your queue/view history?

any idea how old the movie is?

The Nines!  You nailed it!  Awesome.  Thank you so much!

Maybe The Nines from 2007? It's in 3 parts and Ryan Reynolds plays 3 different roles in each of them (Gary, Gavin & Gabriel). But it turn out he's  the same being who's erasing his own memories:

A flashback from Part One shows Gary's P.R. handler, Margaret, telling him he is a God-like being and that God is a 10, humans are a 7 and that he is a 9, therefore he can destroy the world with a single thought, and that he exists in many different forms and that none of them are real.

A man and a woman do intervene near the end to ask him to "come home". Here's the trailer:



